# why doesn't my client read correctly the outputStream sent by the Server?

Tags: java, sockets, stream, client-server, bufferedreader

It's a simple client-server where *Server* using a `BufferedWriter` object would send to the *Client* receiving in the object `BufferedReader`.

When I use `OutputStream` and `PrintWriter` for the *Server* and `InputStream` and `Scanner` for the *Client* it works well.

What happens is that the client in *Buffered* way reads -1 if I'm sending an *int* and *null* for *String*.

I hope my English makes sense. ;P

That's the code:

**Server**:

```
import java.io.*;
import java.net.*;

public class Server {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {

        ServerSocket server = new ServerSocket(8189);
        Socket incoming;

        incoming = server.accept();
        try {
            // OutputStream output = incoming.getOutputStream();
            // PrintWriter outStream = new PrintWriter(output, true /*autoFlush*/);
            // outStream.println("ENTER");
            BufferedWriter output = new BufferedWriter(new           
                                    OutputStreamWriter(incoming.getOutputStream()));
            output.write(3);
            System.out.println("\nSent");

        } finally {
            incoming.close();
        }
    }
}
```

**Client**:

```
import java.io.*;
import java.net.*;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Client {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws UnknownHostException, IOException {

        //Client theClient= new Client();
        Socket RTSPSocket;
        int ServerPort = 8189;
        //server name address
        String ServerHost = "localhost";

        //get Server IP Address
        InetAddress ServerIPAddress = InetAddress.getByName(ServerHost);

        RTSPSocket = new Socket(ServerIPAddress, ServerPort);

        try {
            /*
            InputStream input = theClient.RTSPSocket.getInputStream();
            Scanner in = new Scanner(input);
            String line = in.nextLine();
            System.out.println(line);
            */

            BufferedReader input = new BufferedReader(new  
                                   InputStreamReader(RTSPSocket.getInputStream()));

            //String line = input.readLine();
            //System.out.println("\nRicevuto: " + line);
            System.out.println(input.read());
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.err.println("Error: " + e);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to flush data to receive them in the client part.

```
        output.write(3);
        output.flush();
        System.out.println("\nSent");
```

When you have an OutputStream (or a Writer) you have to flush your data, this way you're 100% sure that what you wanted to be send has been sent.

Most (if not all) the OutputStream subclasses use a "mini buffer" which is flushed only when it's full or you manually call `flush()`. In your case, it's even more flagrant because you're using a `BufferedWriter`.

Another thing, when you use streams/writers, you really should close them after you're finished, one of the main thing `close()` do (most of the time) is flushing the last data remaining in the "mini buffer".

---

**Resources :**

- [Javadoc - OutputStream.flush()](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/OutputStream.html#flush%28%29)

Answer (score 3):

try putting the following code after output.write(3);

```
output.flush();
```

The BufferedOutputStream is built to only send the data when the buffer is full (I believe the default 1024 bytes). So, to force the data to be sent you need to flush the stream.

Comment: Yup.  Also, you'll want to close the BufferedOutputWriter in your finally block.  Doing so will implicitly close the Socket as well, though its usually considered good form to explicitly close both.